# swiftui TextView with action text

Tags: swiftui, uibutton, uikit, swiftui-ontapgesture

Hi everyone I am creating a text editor and I would like to know if there is the possibility to insert a Uibutton in the middle of the text. I am not referring to a url but to a real button.

For now I am creating the editor with a UIViewRepresentable and then with a regex I look for the part of the text to be transformed

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <button id = "4"> consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ornare </button> eget sapien vel gravida.`

My goal is to transform the text between the `<button>` tag into a UIButton or in any case into a tappable text that can perform an action. To understand the equivalent of

```
Button (action: {
    self.mode = "normal"
}) {
    Text ("title")
}
```

some idea? Is it possible to achieve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any picture of what you wanted to design?

Comment: You would likely get mixed results because of the `Button` tap gesture would get mixed with the `UIViewRepresentable/UIButton` gesture

Comment: simply having a part of a tappable text, but not with a url but performing an action like a normal UIButton

Comment: You can do this only at UIKit side, look at NSTextAttachment.

Comment: @Asperi NSTextAttachment seems to only work with images. I would need to have some of the text tappable with actions equal to a button. I was thinking of trying to see if it is possible to set an attribute such as TapGesture action to a part of text in a given Range: